# Migrating users to Universal Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to migrate to the new Universal Membership providers (from a home brew solution). I've migrated our old User table to the Users/Memberships table.

When I run `Membership.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim())`, it always returns false, even though I know the username/password is correct.

Here is how I generated the password, hash, and salt:

```
var salt = Crypto.GenerateSalt();
var hashedPassword = this.GenerateHashWithSalt(password, salt);
```

This is the GenerateHashWithSalt method I'm using

```
private string GenerateHashWithSalt(string password, string salt)
{
    string hashWithSalt = password + salt;
    byte[] saltedHashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashWithSalt);

    HashAlgorithm algo = HashAlgorithm.Create(Membership.HashAlgorithmType);

    byte[] hash = algo.ComputeHash(saltedHashBytes);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

I've also gone with:

```
var salt = Crypto.GenerateSalt();
var saltedPassword = password + salt;
var hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(saltedPassword);
```

Neither of these seem to work. What am I missing?

Scott

Comment: Are you encoding with your home-brew code and validating with Membership provider's default encode method?

Comment: I'm not using home brew for this. I'm using the universal providers. So the user creds are hashed using the HMACSHA256 algorithm w/ salt. Changed how I generate all that. will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, answered it.

So step 1 of all of this was migrating users from our 2-way encrypted passwords to 1 way hash.

Every example I saw of doing that included hashing the password manually. Turns out `Membership.CreateUser(username,password);` hashes the password (and salts), so I was hashing a hashed password, which is why auth was failing.

I simply had to call  Membership.CreateUser, passing in the username & plain text pass, and it worked. Weee!